# How is memory allocated for stack variables?

Tags: c++, c, memory, stack

On VS (release), I run the following:

```
int main(void)
{
   char b[] = "123";
   char a[] = "1234567";
   printf("%x  %x\n", b,a);
   return 0;
}
```

I can see that, the mem address of a is b+3(the length of the string). Which shows that the memory are allocated with no gaps. And this guarantee that least memories are used.
So, I now kind of believe that all compilers will do so. 
I want to make sure of this guess here. Can somebody give me an more formal proof or tell me that my guess is rooted on a coincidence.

Comment: Actually address of a will be b+4. null terminator at the end.

Comment: You might try to add a `short` and `int` variable inbetween them, and see if you theory holds.

Comment: Yes, hitesh, I did wrong with hex calculation. Thanks. And I'm doing more tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed that there will always be perfect packing of data.

For example, I compiled and runned this code on g++, and the difference is 8.

You can read more about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

tl;dr: Compilers can align objects in memory to only addresses divisible by some constant (always machine-word length) to help processor(for them it's easier to work with such addresses)

UPD: one interesting example about alignment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
    char d;
};

struct B
{
    int a;
    int c;
    char b;
    char d;
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(A) << " " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
}
```

For me, it prints

```
16 12
```

Comment: @Andrey Komarov: So a stack works like an object with regard to alignment and padding?

Comment: @user2672165 Stack implementation is compiler-specific. But all objects of the same type would be located similarly to preserve offset of each field from beginning of object. So, for every `a` of type `A` in stack, `(intptr_t)&a.c-(intptr_t)&a` will be the same.

Comment: @Andrey Komarov: Ok. That I know, but as was just curious if the stack memory layout itself had similarities with an object memory layout. It might be a stupid question as I know very little about compiler internals.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee what addresses will be chosen for each variable.  Different processors may have different requirements or preferences for alignment of variables for instance.

Also, I hope there were at least 4 bytes between the addresses in your example.  `"123"` requires 4 bytes - the extra byte being for the null terminator.

Comment: Yes, it's 4 bytes between the two addresses. Well, you mentioned processors, isn't this a compiler-specific thing?

Comment: @RobertBean Yes, compilers are free to do their own thing here.  Mention of different processors was intended as an example of a place where variables wouldn't always be packed in the way I thought you were hinting at.

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the order of declaring a[] and b[], and/or increase the length of b.

You are making a very big assumption about how storage is allocated.  Depending on your compiler the string literals might get stored in a literal pool that is NOT on the stack.  Yet a[] and b[] do occupy elements on the stack.  So, another test would be to add `int c` and compare those addresses.

Comment: Yes, it's big assumption, so I'm far from sure of it. I did some more tests. the order of addresses of a and b are not fixed. But still no crack between the two mem address, they are right to each other.

Comment: @RobertBean when you say right next to each other do you mean by counting chars?  What compiler are you using?  And what machine.

Comment: The literals and their placement are irrelevant, as both `a` and `b` are local arrays.

Comment: @molbdnil depends on the compiler implementation.  String literals can be handled differently compared to other arrays.