# Are stack variables allocated contiguously in virtual memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory, assembly, virtual-memory

I am compiling the below program in C:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
char buffer1[11];
char buffer2[3];
char buffer3[1];
char buffer4[1];
}

void main() {
function(1,2,3);
}
```

using the command:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -S -o example1.s example1.c
```

Below is the output I get:

```
    .file   "example1.c"
    .text
    .globl  function
    .type   function, @function
function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    leave
    ret
    .size   function, .-function
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   $3
    pushl   $2
    pushl   $1
    call    function
    addl    $12, %esp
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The line *subl    $**16**, %esp*  would indicate that 16 bytes is being allotted on the stack.

However as per different tutorials, I can see that stack space is generally allotted in blocks of 4 bytes.

Why is the behaviour I am seeing different?

I am running a 64 bit Ubuntu system:-

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x1b
cpu MHz     : 1202.636
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4988.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Can anyone please help me understand this.

I referred to below question: [How is memory allocated for stack variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181502/how-is-memory-allocated-for-stack-variables)
but I was unable to find a specific answer.

Edit:
1) I would like to understand if the overall stack just has to be aligned to the 4/8/16 byte boundary or each stack variable has to.
2) Is there any limitation for the types of local variables that can be combined into a word of stack memory?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, you declared 16 bytes of locals and you got 16 bytes allocated, which is a multiple of 4. Yeah, the compiler may arrange the locals as it sees fit and the alignment for a `char` is `1` so they can be packed contiguously.

Comment: @Jester I have edited the question. Can you please check now

Comment: the calling convention might desire or require, but I dont think the instruction set requires that alignment.  Those alignments help performance, arm's eabi requires it as well, but at the end of the day it is the specific compiler, version, command line options, whatever that dictate the code generated.  And there is no reason why any two compilers would have to do the same thing.

Comment: The stack is kept aligned because of the followings: 1) aligned memory access are faster 2) some instructions require memory operand to be aligned. Vars (even 1 byte var) are usually allocated in multiple of 4/8/16 byte because of the followings: 1)working with the native word size (4 or 8 bytes) is faster (as it help avoiding false dependencies), even for smaller data type 2) starting with an aligned stack pointer and subtracting only aligned quantities keep the stack aligned. The architecture itself doesn't care about the stack alignment

Comment: The language says almost nothing about how local variables are allocated. What you're asking about is compiler-specific.

Comment: @KeithThompson hmm yes, actually this is a machine and compiler specific question. As mentioned by Steve and knm21 if it is preferred to have variable aligned in memory to 4/8/16 byte, why is gcc not following this approach for individual local variables but only for the overall stack size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that stack variables do not have to be allocated contiguously. In many cases, they are not likely to be.

If you have

```
{
   struct
   {
      int a ;
      char b ;
      double c ;
      char d ;
   } x, y, z; 
}
```

I would wager most compilers would not make the x, y, and z contiguous.

In any event, what you are asking is entirely system and compiler dependent. A compiler does not have to put an auto variable on the stack at all.

Comment: Any specific reason for why gcc is allocating similar typed variables together?

Comment: On some system there is a performance benefit because it takes multiple cycles to retrieved unaligned data. On other systems, unaligned accesses are prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

"1) I would like to understand if the overall stack just has to be aligned to the 4/8/16 bit boundary or each stack variable has to."

This is a machine and compiler specific question.  Generally, variables are aligned according to their size and the CPU word size.  There is a huge advantage to aligning 32-bit variables on 32-bit boundaries on a 32-bit CPU, but there is no advantage to aligning 32-bit variables on an 8-bit CPU, like the 8051.  The 32-bit CPU can only process 32-bit values as 32-bit values if they are aligned on a 32-bit boundary (0x??0, 0x??4, 0x??8, 0x??c).

2) Is there any limitation for the types of local variables that can be combined into a word of stack memory?

No limitation other than alignment.

Comment: Here the pattern I am seeing is if I increase the total number of bytes to 17, then 32 bytes gets allotted on the stack. This had brought me to the conclusion that for gcc in 64 bit systems, when compiled with -m32 flag, it doesnt matter how local variables are aligned but total stack size would be in multiples of 16. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Also is there any specific reason why gcc with -m32 flag is not following this approach of aligning local variables to the 4/8/16 bit boundary?

Comment: @nkvp Both on Windows and Linux the ABI requires the stack to be aligned on 16 **byte** boundaries. On 32 bit machine there is not such requirement but the stack is usually aligned (for example my gcc version still align the stack at 16 byte boundary). **note** that you declared four arrays, arrays must be continuous. An array with 1 char element and one with 16 char elements will (on these machine) take the some space. Also when 16 byte are "allocated" in the stack, this makes room for four 32 bit var or two 64 bit var and so on.

Comment: @nkvp It is not the local vars that are aligned, it is the stack pointer. Often the latter implies the former but not always

Comment: If there is, why does gcc not follow this approach? Are there any flags we can specify to make it follow this approach?

Comment: @nkvp we are talking about **bytes** not bit. gcc follows this, aligning at 16 byte boundaries also imply aligning at 8 and 4 byte boundaries. The performance for alignment is due to 1) How RAM is addressed (e.g. low bits of and address are not actually present on the DRAM controller) which force the use of two reads for non aligned operands in some case and 2) due to some internal CPU architecture.